# django-how to upload main folder and subfolder,subdirectory,subfiles using forms.py and store data main foldername in models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How do keep folder structure when uploading whole folder with sub-folder and files maximum files size 2GB.

what i have tried results in all files saved to the same folder, original folder structure is lost.

`views.py`

```py
def upload_folder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormFiles(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
            for file in files:
              
                myfile = FolderModel(file=file)
                myfile.save()
            return HttpResponse("success")
    else:
        form = FormFiles()
    return render(request, 'folderupload.html', {'form': form})
```

`forms.py`

```py
class FormFiles(forms.Form):
    folder = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True, 'webkitdirectory': True}))
    class Meta:
        model = FolderModel
        fields = ['file']
```

**Expected:**

I store *main* uploaded folder name in database and all the uploaded files with original sub-folder structure go to media storage under *main* folder